# Xcode : changing view size depending on screen size

Tags: ios

I would like to change view size depending on the screen size of the device.
For example, the view should not have the same size on iphone 4s and iphone 6.

The best way would be to use size class, but iphone 4s and iphone 6 are in the same.

Is there a way to add custom size class in order to do that ?

Or should I set auto-layout constraint programmaticaly depending on screen size ?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use Auto-Layout. Here is a good tutorial for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwkpyzn7EOM

Comment: thanks, but I am already using auto layout, but I need to make differents constraints depending on screen size

Comment: I think you set wrong with auto-layout. If it right, it should work.

Comment: Maybe I need to use multiplier (proportionnal) in Autolayout instead of fixed width/height

Comment: Auto-layout should be enough to achieve what you want without having to set different constraints depending on the screen size. You're probably just using it the wrong way.

Could you, please, add a mockup of the screen you're trying to build? Or a screenshot of the storyboard if it doesn't contain some private or NDA-restricted data.

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, in order to show an example I need to build a fake storyboard because of NDA issues...

Answer (score 4):

At this point in time you really only have one solution, and it is using constraints.

Constraints have been existing for a long time now and should be used in all iOS projects. Never EVER change view sizes using their frames. Always adjust the constraint instead.

You can achieve pretty much anything using constraints. There are many tutorials / stack posts about it, you'll be able to look it up.

From what I understand here, you want your view to be bigger on bigger screens, and smaller on smaller screens. Without any other information i can only show you a very trivial example.

Add 4 constraints in storyboard (or in code, but it's just easier in storyboard I believe) from your resizing view to another view. Those four constraints should be Top, Bottom, Leading and Trailing (Up, Down, Left and Right).

Each constraint will basically say "my view should be X units from its superview, on that side".

If you go in the constraints attributes you can configure different things, like "I want my left side to be X units from the right side of that other view".

I suggest you mess around with colored empty views and see how they work, and if you can, have a more experienced programmer answer your questions on the side, because constraints, as simple as they are, are quite confusing at first. It took me about 2 months to be what i consider comfortable with it, and I'm a full time developer.

I can answer a couple more questions here if you want, but I'm pretty sure we'll be off topic really fast !

Have fun using constraints, they're great !

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am also using constraints since 2 months. But I was only setting constant constraint, I figured out that I should use proportional constraint instead.
To set the space between buttons depending of the screen size, I guess I have to do that programmaticaly.

Comment: @NahoumCohen, you can also create an invisible view between buttons and set proportional width constraint for that view instead of changing spacing constraint programmatically.

Comment: It is a super idea ! Thanks !

Comment: Yeah a lot of people do it like that, it works ; i don't specifically like it because it clutters your view with extra views, but it does the job and is quite simple

Comment: But on the other side, changing spacing constraint manually clutters your code :)
Something would be cluttered anyway. You just have to chose, what exactly.